# How to execute a function in an object inside object?

Tags: javascript

I found in stackoverflow a function to shuffle an object, but I need to shuffle the objects inside that object:

For ease of understanding I copied a piece of the object in the console.log:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0:
component: Array(6)
0: {id: 91, type_desc: "enunciado", content: "O novo Guia Alimentar para a PopulaÃ§Ã£o Brasileira"}
1: {id: 92, type_desc: "alternativa", content: "sÃ£o geralmente consumidos em pequenas"}
2: {id: 93, type_desc: "alternativa", content: "sÃ£o formulados e embalados para serem"}
3: {id: 94, type_desc: "alternativa", content: "tendem a ter pouca fibra, em decorrÃªncia da"}
4: {id: 95, type_desc: "alternativa", content: "apresentam embalagens e conteÃºdos diferenciados"}
5: {id: 96, type_desc: "alternativa", content: "possuem uma baixa quantidade de calorias por"}
length: 6
__proto__: Array(0)
id: 16
question_content_id: 1
__proto__: Object
1:
component: Array(6)
0: {id: 31, type_desc: "enunciado", content: "A partir das ideias sugeridas pela charge, avalie as "}
1: {id: 32, type_desc: "alternativa", content: "As asserÃ§Ãµes I e II sÃ£o proposiÃ§Ãµes verdadeiras,"}
2: {id: 33, type_desc: "alternativa", content: "As asserÃ§Ãµes I e II sÃ£o proposiÃ§Ãµes verdadeiras, mas a II nÃ£o"}
3: {id: 34, type_desc: "alternativa", content: "A asserÃ§Ã£o I Ã© uma proposiÃ§Ã£o verdadeira, e a II Ã© "}
4: {id: 35, type_desc: "alternativa", content: "A asserÃ§Ã£o I Ã© uma proposiÃ§Ã£o falsa, e a II Ã© uma"}
5: {id: 36, type_desc: "alternativa", content: "As asserÃ§Ãµes I e II sÃ£o proposiÃ§Ãµes falsas"}
length: 6
__proto__: Array(0)
id: 6
question_content_id: 1
__proto__: Object
```

I used the function in questions, but I want to use in component:

```
api.get("/evaluation/" + this.state.evaluation_id + "/")
                        .then(response => {
                            this.setState({
                                questions: shuffleArray(response.data.question)
)}
```

Comment: Can you please correct your question to use actual arrays? `questions` right now is an object, and `component` within each one is an object as well, not an array. Maybe you meant something like: `questions = [{id: 3, component: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]}]`?

Comment: Assuming side-effects are desired: `shuffleArray(anyExpressionThatEvaluatesToTheArrayToSuffle)`. This expression is no different than accessing the array contents in any other manner. If wishing to shuffle each array in an array of arrays (or similar), this is the same as "for each value in the array, do something over/on/for the value (which happens to be an array)". Recognizing these patterns is valuable.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst it is an object, I correct

Comment: @HiagoBonamelli you can't have multiple identical keys within the same object. `{id: 1, id: 2, id: 3}` will become just `{id: 3}`

Comment: @MatthewHerbst I know, I just copied the values, corrected now

Comment: You haven't corrected anything. You still have an object `component` with identical keys (`id`) in it

Comment: @MatthewHerbst This is not an id of the object, they are ids of my components, I thought it was obvious, i made it clear to you

Comment: @HiagoBonamelli your code does not make sense. Please correct it. Nothing is obvious to us.

Comment: It STILL has the same problem. You should not have multiple identical keys (now, `number`) within the same object.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst I've pasted the console.log object I hope you understand.

Comment: Infinitely better, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some possibilities for solving your problem. One of them consists in implementing the `shuffleQuestions` function, for that you can use your `shuffleArray` function:

```js
function shuffleArray(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex
 
  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex)
    currentIndex -= 1

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex]
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex]
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue
  }

  return array
}

function shuffleQuestions(questions) {
  questions = shuffleArray(questions)
  questions.forEach((v, index) => {
    questions[index]['component'] = shuffleArray(questions[index]['component'])
  })
  return questions
}

let questions = [
  {id: 3, component: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]},
  {id: 1, component: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]},
  {id: 2, component: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]}
]

console.log(shuffleQuestions(questions))
```

I hope I didn't misunderstand your problem

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the array you are saying?

Anyway, I can provide the logic for your problem.
Try this:

```
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        array[i] = shuffleArray(array[i]);
    }

    array = shuffleArray(array);
```

Comment: This shuffles the arrays inside the base array and then finally shuffles the base array.